# Javascript register callback

Tags: javascript

I have a service and want to do the following

```
var service = new Service();
service.onEvent(cb);
var my_module = {
  logged_in(){},
  logged_out(){}
}
function cb(data){
  if (data){
    my_module.logged_in(data);
  } else {
    my_module.logged_out();
  }
}
module.exports = my_module;
```

Then use this module elsewhere:

```
import my_module from 'somefile';
my_module.logged_in = function(data){
  _this.setState({user: data});
}
my_module.logged_out = function(data){
  _this.setState({user: null});
}
```

However, this doesn't work.  The function cb complains that my_module is not defined.

Comment: I can't see any reason why `my_module` wouldn't be defined in the above. (`_this` isn't defined, by `my_module` is.) If I translate that to NodeJS and run it, it works (other than the `_this` problem). Perhaps you've simplified the code for posting so much that the problem's been removed?

Comment: *"I would also like to be able to have my_module call back to multiple places on login."* That's a completely separate question. I've removed it, as a question on SO must be just the *one* question, not two.

Answer (score 0):

JS hoisting did catch you here. The variable declaration as well as the function statement are "hoisted" to the very beginning of the current scope. This means, that the variable `my_module` may be not defined when the service event is fired early.

See:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Comment: What can I do about it in this case to achieve the desired result?

Comment: @Dave: It's impossible for `cb` to be called before `my_module` is assigned in your quoted code. So there's no need to pursue a solution to this, as this isn't the problem. While I would recommend moving your call to `onEvent` to the end just for tidiness (which would address this if it *were* the problem), just before the export, it doesn't matter in your quoted code.